# How to connect multiple wifi device to a server

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a web application in which I make use of socket to connect to wifi device. I was successful in connecting as well as communicating with the connected device. Now I want to connect multiple wifi device to my server. Can anyone help me on this, below is my code

```
public class ScheduleJob extends ServletApp implements Job{

private int port = 1717;
public static String number;
String ReceivedData = "";



public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Starting ... ");

    ServerSocket Sersocket = null;
    System.out.println("Starting the socket server at port:" +port);
    boolean listeningSocket = true;
    try {
        Sersocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 1717");
    }
    try {

        while (listeningSocket) {
            Socket scokt = Sersocket.accept();
            String MachineAdd = scokt.getInetAddress().toString();
            System.out.println("Response-----" +MachineAdd);


            try{

              InputStream inStream = scokt.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inReader);

                ReceivedData = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("ReceivedData :- "+ReceivedData);

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                //Sending the response back to the client.

                OutputStream outStream = scokt.getOutputStream();

                OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outWriter);

                bw.write("hello");
                bw.flush();

        }
        Sersocket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear.  Are you writing code for the server or the clients?  Which one is the code you have shown? What is it about connecting to the server that you are having problems with?

Comment: the above code is of server. I have wifi device which acts like a client. now i am able to send request from client and connect to server only one device. i want my server to accept request of multiple clients and interact with them.

Comment: Ah, for that you have to run each connection on its own thread.  Put your code for handling each client in its own class that inherits from `Runnable` then launch a thread for each new incoming connection.  Google "multithreaded network server java" for tutorials.

Comment: can you please give me an example code if you have.

Comment: Sorry, that is not the way StackOverflow works. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  You are capable of reading and following the tutorials.  Writing a multi-threaded network server is not a trivial task and you should make the effort to learn how to do it.